# How to minimize application as soon as it started?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How can I minimize application as soon as it starts up to run it at the background in Windows Mobile 6? I want to minimize application it is launch automatically (i.e. auto-starts) and when later, if user wants to see application, it can run from the Program menu etc.

I tried some of the code but it does not work!

Traditional minimize scheme, although it will not solve my problem as using this code will never show the application to the user again (even this code does not work)

```
private void GUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    
     this.Hide();
     this.Visible = false;
}
```

and second option is to call native API (source: http://www.blondmobile.com/2008/04/windows-mobilec-how-to-minimize-your_5311.html)

```
private void GUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                    
     this.HideApplication();
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_MINIMIZED = 6;

public void HideApplication()
{
      ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
}
```

Second code does work from any other part of the program, but not from Load Event.

Comment: The second method does not work in the Load Event, because the form is not fully initialized and therefore it can't minimize it yet.
Have you tried calling HideApplication in OnActivated or OnShow?

Comment: It works, I think I should use a varible to hide it once only!

Comment: No, it didn't work OnActivated event, so the only solution is timer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I thought is using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and It works

```
private void GUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
// Initialize timer to hide application when automatically launched
_hideTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
_hideTimer.Interval = 0; // 0 Seconds
_hideTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_hideTimer_Tick);
_hideTimer.Enabled = true;
}

// Declare timer object
System.Windows.Forms.Timer _hideTimer;
void _hideTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Disable timer to not use it again
    _hideTimer.Enabled = false;
    // Hide application
    this.HideApplication();
    // Dispose timer as we need it only once when application auto-starts
    _hideTimer.Dispose();
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_MINIMIZED = 6;

public void HideApplication()
{
      ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
}
```